# Hay diet's effectiveness

Tags: diet, protein, carbohydrate

Does the Hay diet (essentially not mixing protein based food with carbohydrate based foods in the same meal) actually produce good results? Are such restrictions unhealthy or excessive?

Comment: I've not heard about this.  I have heard about not mixing fats and carbs in a meal though.  I always thought you should have protein with just about every meal.

Comment: Do you have an idea what the diet would be founded on? And perhaps do you have any reason to doubt its effectiveness? Perhaps you don't understand why it would help or that its not nutritious enough. I suggest you edit that into the question.

Comment: [And here's an interesting link for anyone interested in the diet's background](http://www.diet.com/g/hay-diet)

Comment: @Ivo Flipse, what you suggest in the edit is implied from the question's present state, if you feel it's convoluted, why not make the edit yourself.

Comment: I try to nudge users into doing such things themselves, so they hopefully learn how to do it better next time. If I would edit every question myself, users might start relying on me doing it for them, rather than putting in some effort themselves :-)

Comment: Off topic according to the [FAQ] since the scope change of the site excluded questions not related to exercise.

Answer (score 2):

I have never heard this called the 'Hay diet', but I am familiar with the concepts involved here.  From my learning, it's simply called 'food matching', and simply talk about which foods should be eaten with which.  The basics, as I've learned them, go like this and are pretty simple:

- Do not eat grain and meat at the same time.
- Fruit (including berries) should be eaten alone.
- Vegetables go with anything.

That's it.  The thought behind it is to not give your stomach things with two different digestive needs at one time.  I've mainly seen it used in people with chronic heartburn and other stomach problems, and the results there have definitely been very, very good.  I know 3 people personally who had heartburn almost every day of their lives for 10 or more years experience relief inside of a week.  I have never seen food matching used in terms of weight loss or athletic training, so I cannot comment there.